# rails find_or_create_by is slow when database contains 100k records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I noticed that `find_or_create_by` in rails slowing data ingestion, although I have an index set on the `SELECT` fields. any suggestions on how to speed this up?  I'm using postgres

Comment: Are you sure that your index covers all needed columns? How does your query look like, how does the index look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_or_create_by` is nothing but simply `where` query with `limit 1` and if result is `NULL` it will fire `insert` query to return new object.

If you have added indexing properly to columns then it will be faster as much as it is supposed to be.

But for large database you described, I will suggest you to run such operations in background using [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Comment: interesting, I did not know about sidekiq, I will give a shot. thanks

Comment: how to handle dependent queries in sidekiq. like for example, adding a new name record and getting the id of that record, and use that record id for the next insertion as foreign id?